# How to remove some variables in R with names that are dates

Tags: r, date, variables, time-series

I have a dataset in R where some of the variable names are dates, see a simplified example of the input data below (in Excel):

[image: starting data point]

What I want to do with this data is to remove some of the columns with names that are dates that are older than or equal to a certain date, e.g. 2019-01-31. See a simplified example of the desired output data below (in Excel):

[image: desired output data]

Now, I am able to achieve this by transposing the data, filtering out rows with a date lower than or equal to 31 January 2019 and finally transposing the data back. However I am wondering whether there is a different way to do this using just the column names without pivoting back and forth?

```
# Example data to copy and paste into R for easy reproduction of problem:

df <- data.frame (id = c("apples",  "pears",    "grapes",   "tomatoes", "carrots",  "cucumber", "rabbit",   "cat",  "dog"),
type    = c("fruit",    "fruit",    "fruit",    "veggies",  "veggies",  "veggies",  "pets", "pets", "pets"),
color   = c("red",  "green",    "purple",   "red",  "orange",   "green",    "grey", "black",    "brown"),
'2019-04-30'    = c(353,    91, 270,    2029,   107,    62, 30, 61, 137),
'2019-03-31'    = c(349,    90, 267,    2028,   104,    60, 29, 59, 133),
'2019-02-28'    = c(345,    89, 264,    2027,   101,    58, 28, 57, 129),
'2019-01-31'    = c(341,    88, 261,    2026,   98, 56, 27, 55, 125),
'2018-12-31'    = c(337,    87, 258,    2025,   95, 54, 26, 53, 121),
'2018-11-30'    = c(333,    86, 255,    2024,   92, 52, 25, 51, 117),
check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: You can consider using `dplyr::select` in combination with `dplyr::starts_with` or `dplyr::select_if` https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html

Comment: `select_if` won't work b/c it selects based on the values in the **columns** (not the header. `starts_with` uses a string prefix to match, nothing you could use for comparing a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this in base R. Your dates are conveniently in YYYY-MM-DD format, which means they will be ordered correctly by the `>=` and `<=` operators. We can also use a simple regex to preserve any columns that are not in date format:

```
df[!grepl('\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}', colnames(df)) | colnames(df) >= '2019-02-28']

        id    type  color 2019-04-30 2019-03-31 2019-02-28
1   apples   fruit    red        353        349        345
2    pears   fruit  green         91         90         89
3   grapes   fruit purple        270        267        264
4 tomatoes veggies    red       2029       2028       2027
5  carrots veggies orange        107        104        101
6 cucumber veggies  green         62         60         58
7   rabbit    pets   grey         30         29         28
8      cat    pets  black         61         59         57
9      dog    pets  brown        137        133        129
```

Comment: Neat +1. Requires, however, that all columns are indeed formatted as seen. Valid dates like '2021-2-4'  would break the code, but from the screenshot we can assume that all column headers seem to be formated int `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1):

The approach is as follows:

- extract the column names
- transform to `Date` if possible and `NA` if not date like
- create boolean vector to filter too old dates and non dates (i.e. `NAs` in the step before) columns

### Sample Data

```r
## sample data frame
m <- matrix(1, 3, 10)
colnames(m) <- c("a", "b", as.character(seq.Date(as.Date("2021-1-1"), length.out = 8, by = "days")))
(d <- as.data.frame(m))
#   a b 2021-01-01 2021-01-02 2021-01-03 2021-01-04 2021-01-05 2021-01-06 2021-01-07 2021-01-08
# 1 1 1          1          1          1          1          1          1          1          1
# 2 1 1          1          1          1          1          1          1          1          1
# 3 1 1          1          1          1          1          1          1          1          1
```

### Filter

```r
r <- vapply(names(d), as.Date, numeric(1), optional = TRUE)
d[, is.na(r) | r <= as.Date("2021-1-3")]
#   a b 2021-01-01 2021-01-02 2021-01-03
# 1 1 1          1          1          1
# 2 1 1          1          1          1
# 3 1 1          1          1          1

r <- vapply(names(df), as.Date, numeric(1), optional = TRUE)
df[, is.na(r) | r >= as.Date("2019-1-31")]
#         id    type  color 2019-04-30 2019-03-31 2019-02-28 2019-01-31
# 1   apples   fruit    red        353        349        345        341
# 2    pears   fruit  green         91         90         89         88
# 3   grapes   fruit purple        270        267        264        261
# 4 tomatoes veggies    red       2029       2028       2027       2026
# 5  carrots veggies orange        107        104        101         98
# 6 cucumber veggies  green         62         60         58         56
# 7   rabbit    pets   grey         30         29         28         27
# 8      cat    pets  black         61         59         57         55
# 9      dog    pets  brown        137        133        129        125
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Description

One can re-shape the data to the long format and filter based on the date column.

#### Data

Same data as provided in the example

```
df <- data.frame (id = c("apples",  "pears",    "grapes",   "tomatoes", "carrots",  "cucumber", "rabbit",   "cat",  "dog"),
type    = c("fruit",    "fruit",    "fruit",    "veggies",  "veggies",  "veggies",  "pets", "pets", "pets"),
color   = c("red",  "green",    "purple",   "red",  "orange",   "green",    "grey", "black",    "brown"),
'2019-04-30'    = c(353,    91, 270,    2029,   107,    62, 30, 61, 137),
'2019-03-31'    = c(349,    90, 267,    2028,   104,    60, 29, 59, 133),
'2019-02-28'    = c(345,    89, 264,    2027,   101,    58, 28, 57, 129),
'2019-01-31'    = c(341,    88, 261,    2026,   98, 56, 27, 55, 125),
'2018-12-31'    = c(337,    87, 258,    2025,   95, 54, 26, 53, 121),
'2018-11-30'    = c(333,    86, 255,    2024,   92, 52, 25, 51, 117),
check.names = FALSE)
```

#### Solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = !c(id, type, color), names_to = 'date', values_to = 'value') %>%
  dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')) %>%
  dplyr::filter( date >= as.Date('2019-01-31')) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = 'date', values_from = 'value')
```

#### Desired output

```
  id       type    color  `2019-04-30` `2019-03-31` `2019-02-28` `2019-01-31`
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 apples   fruit   red             353          349          345          341
2 pears    fruit   green            91           90           89           88
3 grapes   fruit   purple          270          267          264          261
4 tomatoes veggies red            2029         2028         2027         2026
5 carrots  veggies orange          107          104          101           98
6 cucumber veggies green            62           60           58           56
7 rabbit   pets    grey             30           29           28           27
8 cat      pets    black            61           59           57           55
9 dog      pets    brown           137          133          129          125
```

Comment: This is the current solution that I have. But thanks for showing it in code also for people to see (maybe I should have done so above to begin with).